# REST API for JIRA 7.3.5

Tags: jira, jira-rest-api

JIRA version 7.3.5 does not supports SOAP APIs, hence I want to migrate my code from SOAP to REST APIs.

**PROBLEM STATEMENT**:

For a given JIRA ID, i want the API which can return me the JIRA details:

**For Example**:

If I query for "Issue Type", the API should return one of the following types:

```
Issue Type:

New Feature
Support
Bug 
Change Request
Story
Epic
Summary Task
Task
Documentation
```

Similarly, i want to get the result for other details such as "Status", "Priority", "Resolution", "Labels", "Severity" etc. etc.

I'm new to REST APIs and hence unable to locate the exact documentation for same.

I referred to following documentation but it didn't help much:
https://docs.atlassian.com/software/jira/docs/api/REST/7.3.5/

Answer (score 0):

If you use the endpoint `GET /rest/api/2/issue/{issueIdOrKey}` you get back a representation of the issue. In that there is `fields.issueType` which contains name (probably what you need) but also a more thorough description, id and link to the definition, icon etc.

Comment: Thanks @Roger. I will check that.